# How to count percent of tablet devices in google console or firebase console?

Tags: android, firebase, google-play, firebase-analytics

Is there a way to calculate how many tablet devices has my application?
I found only all devices but It doestn't solve my problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run below query in BigQuery ( replace XXX with your server config )

```
select device.category, count(device.category),
count(device.category) * 100.0 / (select count(*) from `XXX.events_*`) as device_percent
from `XXX.events_*` 
group by device.category
```

Edit : If you want to filter duplicate based on another column. Use below variant ( replace XXX with your server config and device.advertising_id with column name)

```
select  device.category, count( DISTINCT device.advertising_id),
count( DISTINCT device.advertising_id ) * 100.0 / (select count(*) from (select DISTINCT device.advertising_id from `XXX.events_*`)) as device_percent
from `XXX.events_*` 
group by device.category
```

Comment: thank you, exactly what I need! Do you know how to choose range of data sets? It's collected by day now and .events_* doesn't work, only exact table

Comment: I found that I miss #standardSQL tag. Now It's working now.

Answer (score 0):

If you wand split the different device model, you can add the filter like the picture.

[image]

Usually, need the code support that.